# Add custom field when admin add new user (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, admin, field, addition

I'm interested how can I add a field (as input), when the administrator adds a new user (Wordpress). Not when a user registers, but only when the administrator adds a new user. I found on the net for example, but only for fields that are to edit the user, but I want to add in the addition of new users. And new data from the input-and save them in user meta table. Is anyone doing this exercise.

Comment: If it is another default field *(biography, aim, jabber)*, it's possible, otherwise I think not.

Answer (score 8):

<s>Revisiting this interesting Question, I'd say that no, **it's not possible**.</s>

Analyzing the file [**`/wp-admin/user-new.php`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/user-new.php), there is **no action hook** that would allow that. Even following the functions used in the `<form>` led to nowhere.

A possible and dirty solution would be injecting the fields with jQuery.

When adding the new user to the database, we could use the hook [**`user_profile_update_errors`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L153) to update the user meta (as a hack too).

**Update:** A new field can be added with:

```
add_action( 'user_new_form', function( $type ){
    if( 'add-new-user' !== $type )
        return;
    echo '<input type="text" name="custom_user_field" id="custom_user_field" value=""/>';
});
```

And to get the posted data and process it, use:

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', function( $data )
{
    if ( is_wp_error( $data->errors ) && ! empty( $data->errors ) ) 
        return;

    # Do your thing with $_POST['custom_user_field'] 
    wp_die( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) ) );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since wordpress 3.7 there is a hook for this.

Use the hook "user_new_form". It fires just before the submit button is inserted.
This way you can display your own custom fields in the new user form.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the "user_profile_update_errors" hook suggested here didn't give me the user_id to allow me to save the meta fields.
Therefore I changed to using "user_register" as in the code below.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

```
//  add fields to new user form
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'mktbn_user_new_form' );

function mktbn_user_new_form()
{
?>    

<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="business_name">Company </label></th>
        <td><input name="business_name" type="text" id="business_name" value=""></td>
    </tr>    

    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="business_type">Profession </label></th>
        <td><input name="business_type" type="text" id="business_type" value=""></td>
    </tr>    

    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="user_mobile">Mobile </label></th>
        <td><input name="user_mobile" type="text" id="user_mobile" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


<?php   
}

//  process the extra fields for new user form
add_action( 'user_register', 'mktbn_user_register', 10, 1 );

function mktbn_user_register( $user_id )
{
    mikakoo_log( 'user_register: ' . $user_id );

    if ( isset( $_POST['business_name'] ))
    {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'business_name', $_POST['business_name']);
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['business_type'] ))
    {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'business_type', $_POST['business_type']);
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_mobile'] ))
    {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_mobile', $_POST['user_mobile']);
    }
}
```